# Releasing MIDI key causes a sound - using Ableton Live - how to avoid that?

Tags: recording, midi-controller-keyboard, ableton-live

When I play some instruments in Ableton Live 9 with my MIDI controller, e.g. a "Stranger Lead Guitar" or "Steel jazz clean," it plays sound when I hit the key, which is good, but it also plays a sound when I release the key, which I would like to avoid. It creates a very bad sound in my FX chain.

Is there any way to modify the instrument or sound so that it does not play upon key release? Why does this happen for some instruments and not for others?

Comment: Some are programmed to respond to note off or velocity zero with a 'lift' sound, a string scrape for a guitar, key-lifting sound for a piano etc. You might have to dig into the particular instruments parameters & see if you can dig it out.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, the thing is I have no clue where to look for this within Ableton

Comment: Sorry, I've not really used it myself.

Comment: This is very much a virtual instrument specific question. What instrument package are you using?

Comment: It is bundled within the ableton live 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I looked into it and it seems what is annoying you is a delay that is in the chain of effects next to the instrument. Specifically in "jazz guitar clean", it is associated with the reverb knob control and if you turn it all the way to the left the delay should stop ringing. Now, since there are other effects in that chain, that you might want to leave running, I suggest you delete the "simple delay" effect out of the track effect chain, and then you could keep the reverb knob up without that specific sound you want to get rid of.

Comment: Hi, it seems like I cannot affect the track effect chain, not even to view it. I can see the basic 8 knobs and nothing more to the left or right. If I right click on the tab in the bottom below, I can see a context menu saying some effects but clicking on the items of the menu does nothing. It looks like this: http://i.snag.gy/wLOlh.jpg

Comment: Ok, a short google search returned https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=146337 that it is because I use lite and I cannot edit it, becaues it is a preset. So I guess an upgrade is necessary.